# KendoUI: TabStrip Redirect Page in Content of Tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-ui

I have a TabScript and in the content of that TabScript I have a button. So when I click on the button it will redirect to the other page. But is there any way to make it just redirect in the content of the TabScript, not refresh the page?

Thanks!

Comment: A sample of your code would help here..

Answer (score 1):

When the buttons is clicked you can perform you own [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) request and set the result returned from the server to be the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) of the [contentElement](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#methods-contentElement).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I still don't know how to make it work. I'm a new in Kendo. Would you please give me an example?